# SQL Query not retrieving anything

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

***I have 2 tables:***

**Equipas:**
*codEquipa* **(which is the table's primay key)**
nomeEquipa
logoEquipa
estadioEquipa
cidadeEquipa

**Jogo:**
*codJogo* **(which is the table's primay key)**
codEquipaCasa **(which is the foreign key for codEquipa)**
codEquipaFora **(which is the foreign key for codEquipa)**
dataJogo

**And have a query:***

```
SELECT  Equipa.nomeEquipa AS "Casa", 
        Equipa.nomeEquipa AS "Visitante" 
FROM Equipa 
JOIN Jogo AS j1 ON j1.codEquipaCasa=Equipa.codEquipa 
JOIN Jogo AS j2 ON j2.codEquipaFora=Equipa.codEquipa
```

The thing is that i have one registry in Jogo with existant foreign keys but the query don't retrieve me anything.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.
Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Removed the Sql-Server tag based on the sql syntax.

Comment: put some sample data if possible

Comment: why do you have 2 same columns (Equipa.nomeEquipa) in select section of the query? Did you try LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Because i have a two connection from one table to another to make the visitor team and the home one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `join` `Equipa` twice to `Jogo`, not the other way around:

```
SELECT ec.nomeEquipa AS "Casa", 
       ef.nomeEquipa AS "Visitante" 
FROM Jogo j JOIN
     Equipa ec
     ON j.codEquipaCasa = ec.codEquipa JOIN
     Equipa ef
     ON j.codEquipaFora = ef.codEquipa;
```

If there are missing values, then you might want `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, that made it through. And know i understand this JOIN statement

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Equipa is the table you're trying to join twice, not Jogo.
If I understood your question correctly, try this:

```
SELECT  e1.nomeEquipa AS "Casa",
        e2.nomeEquipa AS "Visitante"
FROM Jogo j
JOIN Equipa AS e1 ON j.codEquipaCasa=e1.codEquipa 
JOIN Equipa AS e2 ON j.codEquipaFora=e2.codEquipa
```